# Mouse cursor changes theme in Firefox

Tags: themes, cursor

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with BSPWM as my window manager.

I was following the Arch Wiki's [Arch Wiki's guide for cursor themes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Cursor_themes) and everything seemed to work when I wanted to change the default cursor theme with one of the other default themes. This worked for all programs. Now, I wanted to add a custom theme from gnome-lookup.org. I added it to the required folder, but then when I followed the steps, the theme seemed to be installed for every application but FireFox.

Does anybody know why some themes work for firefox and some don't?

Comment: because FF is installed as a snap perhaps and thus sandboxed?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to Linux. Could you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Applications packaged as a Snap, such as Firefox in Ubuntu 22.04 and higher, are not capable of using custom icon themes. They may become able to do that in the future, but until then, you have to stick with the current situation, or workaround it by using alternative software packaging formats. For Firefox, the most obvious action may be to install a regular .deb version directly from  Mozilla. With [this procedure](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04), you add a PPA such that the browser is automatically being updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are Certain Application packages in Ubuntu and other Debian-based systems that are called snaps, which are applications that have dependencies built in. Not all app packages are snaps, others are simple .deb packages. What @24601 was saying is that Firefox may have been installed as a snap package instead of a normal application from the ubuntu software center, but I don't think that is the problem, even if that is true. Firefox comes pre-installed on ubuntu and thus Firefox might not have been affected by the cursor change since it is built in. You might see that Thunderbird, Settings and other pre-installed applications aren't affected by the cursor change. Try uninstalling Firefox and reinstalling it again from the ubuntu software center.

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox from ubuntu software will simply replace the snap version.

Comment: You do not think that snap is the problem. That may be an erroneous assumption. Yes, snap is the problem: it does not use the system wide cursor theme.